# Contentflow auto resize issues

Tags: javascript, contentflow

I'm using this javascript plugin: http://jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/

Well, I'm a beginner in js programming and I have this problem:

When I resize the browser window, the images are reduced too. But i don't have any idea how to turn off the resize function. I tried to comment many lines of codes that have .resize or something but it didn't work. I was searching on google but with no success for the answer, I hope someone could help me here :/

Comment: Can you show any code or create http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: i created this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ramon_v/9j7cP/

Answer (score 0):

did you try to style the class item with fix width because I think this is the issue.

As I can see the class item is use on each div and everything is set with % width.

```
.item{
 width:200px;
}
```

note that I put 200px but choose the size you want.

Comment: It worked, but when i use it on `.item` all containers receives this value. and when i use it on `.item .active` it changes only the active, but the others dont get the correct width to calculate, they decrease and for some reason the div `#legenda` decrease in all the containers.
here`s the css code for `#legenda`:
`#legenda {width:100%; height:34px !important; background-color:#d0952e;}`

Comment: Because up the the first div below the maincontent, you may want to add a class to it and style it the width you want. That will fix the issue. The problem is because everything is in % and fix width is needed.